# Является ли выражение просторечным?

Tags: стилистика

Верно ли выражение: *А мягкое банное мыло черного и белого цвета до сих пор популярно среди женщин за натуральный состав и необычное исполнение*.

Comment: Уточните,. какая часть вызывает сомнения. Просторечий я тут не вижу, ни явных, ни дискуссионных даже. Если что и вижу - некоторое косноязычие и/или тяжеловесность всей конструкции.

Answer (score 3):

Выражение неверно: можно ценить что-то (или проявлять к нему иное отношение действием) за какое-то полезное свойство. Для сочетаемости с предлогом и падежом нужно данное отношение выразить глаголом или причастием (а здесь - краткое прилагательное "популярно" = "является популярным"; его можно связать с остальным напр. оборотом "по причине того-то", а с "за" выходит будто оно само себя за всё названное делает популярным среди женщин).

`А мягкое банное мыло черного и белого цвета до сих пор ценится/любимо` `женщинами (= женщины до сих пор ценят) за натуральный состав и необычное` `исполнение.`

Answer (score 2):

А мягкое банное мыло черного и белого цвета до сих пор популярно среди женщин за натуральный состав и необычное исполнение.

-Вы хотели сказать "разговорным", а не "просторечным"? Было бы разговорным, если б была лексика разговорная, а с лексикой здесь всё в порядке, нарушена лексическая сочетаемость: популярно ЗА состав и исполнение.

Можно исправить: 1) популярно по причине натурального состава и необычного исполнения; 2) популярно из-за натурального состава и необычного исполнения;3) популярно, так как имеет натуральный состав и необычное исполнение 4) ...привлекает женщин натуральным составом и необычным  исполнением и ещё много вариантов. Только вот о каком необычном исполнении идёт речь, не понимаю.